# How to give more space form left back button on default header in react native?

Tags: html, css, react-native, flexbox, jsx

I am trying to add some space on back button from left side of the header in my code (`React native`), But it's not working.

```
headerStyle: {
        paddingLeft: 60
      }
```

[image]

I have also tried to add marginLeft but it's also not working. Margin added over all header and header is misaligned from bottom details.

```
headerStyle: {
        marginLeft: 30
      }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I applied `padding-start` instead of `padding-left` or `margin-left` in CSS, It's working as i aspected.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an Icon component for the 'back button', so try adding marginLeft directly to the Icon component but not to the Header component.

Comment: Actually it's not a separate icon component, it's default header which i use in react native. Not picking the margin and padding on header left where the back button is coming